# Can't load DBF attribute table correctly - QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dbf

I'm trying to load in QGIS a shapefile with an edited DBF file. The objects are loaded correctly, but not the attribute table, which mixes the data from different cells.
It is a very large DBF with 12637010 rows, edited as a CSV file, but saved as DBF in EmEditor. It seens to be a delimitation problem, but  don't know how to change it in DBF.

Comment: Odds are, you corrupted the shapefile when you edited the `.dbf`. It's backup restoration time.

Comment: It's generally not a great idea to directly edit the dbf from a shapefile in a text editor, Excel, etc. Like @Vince said, it is very easy to unintentionally make changes that corrupt a shapefile. Better to load the shapefile in QGIS and edit attribute values there.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt return! Since I'm dealing with large files, when I load the shapefile in QGIS it reduces the number of objects. I did the segmentation in eCognition, classification in Weka's Random Forest and I'm trying to get the result back to GIS so I can see it. This last step is being painful considering the amount of data.

Comment: In a shapefile the shx file links the shapes of the shp file to the records of the dbf file.  Any additions or deletions of records, or sorts, or other changes can screw up the link and corrupt your shapefile.  You might consider setting your data up so that you can manipulate your tables in other software and then when done join them to the shapes using unique values in a shared field.  If needed export that to a new shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

First check the delimitation symbols when loading the table in QGIS and make sure that the encoding of the DBF file matches the encoding used in your CSV file. Common encodings include UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, and others. Use a text editor that allows you to specify the encoding to ensure consistency